# Personal library project, how to solve this?

Tags: c++

I have this personal library management project. I have some Lists of derivate classes of `Media` and a List of `Person`. I must also have a list of `Loan` that refer to an instance of a `Media` and an instance of `Person`. I implemented this using two pointers in the class `Loan`. 
The problem is that the user must be able to delete instances in the `Media` and `Person` lists. My question is, how do I check that there is no `Loan` pointing to that instance in order to prevent the user from deleting it?
You can also suggest me a better way to implement the `Loan` class if it is the case.

I con provide more information on the structure of the project if you need it.
Please consider that this is a project for an introductory C++ OO course, so I would avoid use of too advanced techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with very simple C++ code then you have a number of ways that you could achieve this.  You could just loop through all the Loans and check that none of them are for the Person or Media you are trying to delete.

Alternatively just as Loan refers to the instance of Person and Media that it is for you could make Person and Media also hold a reference to the Loan. One advantage of this approach is you can easily detect when a Media item is already on loan, complications are that a Person could have more than one Media item on loan and there is more housekeeping to do when a Media item is returned.

Comment: I implemented a simple reference counting system: the `Media` and `Person` class have an `int` counter that is incremented and decremented by the `Loan` instances when they are created and destroyed. When the program wants to remove an instance of Media, it checks this counter and if it is > 0 it alerts the user. Is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

Reference counting and shared pointers, though it's doubtful that this is accepted in your introductory course. Consequently I'd suggest that your design ought to be revisited to avoid the multiple-references.

Comment: How would I implement a basic reference counting?